# Compare dates as strings

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I can't find a way to find all the dates(strings) less then at least one year from now.

i keep in database Date Field strings  like "DateTime.toShortDateString()" and i need to compare now.

it looks like month/day/year  = 9/6/2011

its need to be lower at least one year from DateTime.now.

i did this and it doesnt return all dates needed just few.

```
        DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
        int Year = Date.Year;
        Year -= 1;
        int Month = Date.Month;
        string MonthYear = Month.ToString() + "%" + Year.ToString();
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DateOrder < @STU ";

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STU", MonthYear);
```

This is my problem

Comment: So you have serialized DateTimes as strings and would like to compare these dates to one another. Why not deserialize them, and then compare as DateTime objects?

Comment: Why do you want to compare them as strings?

Comment: So what are you asking? What do you need from us?

Comment: Are you locked into comparing them as strings? Comparing dates in their native format will be faster.

Comment: Please specify which flavor of SQL you are talking. I assume Microsoft SQL Server based on the language, but you should be clear.

Comment: its need to be lower at least one year FROM DATETIME.NOW

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)` gives you the date exactly one year from now.

Comment: @Starter if you're looking to do something if the date you're loaded is further than a year from now, I've added to my answer to help you do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your database schema and store dates as `char(10)` in ISO 8601 format (`yyyy-mm-dd`) or the ISO 8601 compact form (`yyyymmdd`).

- http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

That gives you proper collation and proper comparison. Further...DateTime.Parse() and TryParse() will both accept that format regardless of culture (well..one exception: Saudi Arabia, ar-SA. Go figure). `DateTime.ToString("Y") or`string.Format( "{0:Y}" , someDateTimeInstance )` will give you the ISO 8601 format.

Should be a simple update to your database.

Even better, if you're using SQL Server 2008: store dates using the new datatype `Date`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe deserialize these DateTime strings and then compare as DateTime objects?

```
var date=DateTime.Parse(stringFromDb, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Then you can do:

```
if (dateToCompare1 < dateToCompare2)
```

Or whatever comparison operator you want.

**Edit**: from your comment, I think you would like use only dates that are later (or equal to?) one year from now. And so you would do:

```
var date=DateTime.Parse(stringFromDb, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
if (date >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) {
   // Do whatever you want with the "kept" dates
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a string:

```
string strDate1 = "09/06/2011";
string strDate2 = "09/06/2011";

DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(strDate1);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(strDate2);
```

Then compare them.